# "A is faster than B by 40%"

Tags: sentence-construction, mathematics

I am trying to understand how to compare speeds in English.
I have two types of devices that do the same thing. Their performances are measured in operations per second.

Let's say I have Device A that operates 17 times per second and device B that operates 12 times per second. Is it correct to say that:

> Device A is faster than B by 41.7%?

because (17 - 12)/12 is approximately 0.417. How should it be (17 - 12)/17 = 0.294? That means the following is correct

> Device A is faster than B by 29.4%?

Also I wonder what are some other ways I can say one device is more/less efficient than the other?

Comment: This seems to be a question about mathematics more than English. I'm sure the same rule applies in any language. "*Device A 41.7% faster*", or "*Device B is 29.4% slower*".

Comment: 12 is to 100 as 17 is to.... ?

Comment: @gotube but it is correct to say that "Device A is faster than Device B _by_ 41.7%"?

Comment: Yes. 17/12 = 1.416666666... or 1.417 to 3 decimal places.  17 is 141.7% of 12, or 41.7% greater.

Answer (score 1):

17 / 12 = 1.42 = **"This device is 42% faster than that device."**

12 / 17 = 0.71 = (1 - 0.29) = **"This device is 29% slower than that device."**

17 - 12 = 5 = **"This device performs 5 operations per second more than that device."**

12 - 17 = -5 = **"This device performs 5 operations per second less than that device."**

Comment: Some might say 'This device performs five operations per second fewer than that device', or even 'five fewer operations per second'.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about `(17-12)/12` versus `(17-12)/12`.The convention is that the denominator is the value of the item being compared **to**, which in your examples is the one mentioned after the word "than". So in:

> …A is [something] **than** B

A is being compared **to** B and so B goes on the denominator.

By contrast, you would put A in the denominator if the sentence was:

> …B is [something] **than** A

One area to be careful with is when the quantities you are comparing are themselves percentages. So, suppose A=17% and B=12% were the profit percentages of two companies. Then strictly speaking we could still say that:

> A is more profitable than B by 41.7%

but a common alternative is to say that:

> A is more profitable than B by 5 *percentage points*

NOTE: in the first part of my answer, I focused on what goes on the denominator, and I ignored the order of items on the *numerator*. That's because we're usually looking for the absolute value (sign ignored), and the order doesn't matter for that. Of course it *does* matter when deciding whether to use "smaller" or "larger", say, but I'm assuming you get that already.