# A is xx% higher than B

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Almost the same as the question ["A is faster than B by 40%"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/317436/a-is-faster-than-b-by-40), but unlike the comment of *"This seems to be a question about mathematics more than English."*, to me this is *still* an English question as it is still about how to express comparison in English. But I do agree that you have to understand mathematics to answer this question, which comes from the following Q & A:

---

**Q**: *The figure recorded in Feb, 25, is 15% higher than it should be. What's the actual figure?*

**Solution**:
We need to calculate how much is 15% out of 25. (25x15)/100= 3.75
So the actual figure is 25 - 15% = 25 - 3.75 = 21.25

---

Me and my friend think that the *"Solution"* is wrong, but want to double check here to see if our understanding might be wrong.

Comment: I'd certainly answer ~21.74. If A is 15% higher than B it implies that it's a percentage of B regardless of which of A and B is known and which is unknown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["A is faster than B by 40%"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/317436/a-is-faster-than-b-by-40)